# How can I get rid of the 20,000 files on my desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, batch-file, file-management

So i was bored in class at school, and so wrote this .bat file really quickly, for a bit of fun

```
SET \A x=0
:loop
SET \A x=%x%+1
echo hehe>bruh%x%.txt
goto :loop
```

This created around 20,000 files on the desktop named 'bruh1.txt,bruh2.txt,bruh3.txt'

Now, the computer is not able to open any programs, and none of the items on the desktop are showing. File explorer seems to restart itself every 20 seconds or so. I don't know how I could fix this without asking the IT admins, but this would probably land me in a spot of trouble. Any ways to fix this?

Can't just delete with file explorer, because again, it simply will not open.

Comment: Win-R to bring up the run command dialog, then run `cmd`? from there you should be able to navigate to your desktop and `del bruh*.txt` ?

Comment: write a .bat file real quick to delete all files starting with "bruh"

Comment: So you gave yourself a virus and intentionally ran it? That's pretty comical. Next time you want to watch your computer suffer like that just make a Travelling Salesman program with visual feedback.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comment by Mokubai, press
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and then type `cmd` and press OK,
and enter the following two commands:

```
cd %userprofile%\Desktop
del bruh*.txt
```

Comment: Hopefully, the machines don't have OneDrive installed and syncing

Comment: Lol........................